# Did Krishna fail in his quest to restore dharma to the world?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, kali-yuga

Kali yuga was on the door anyway, and even the time before wasn't marked by righteouusness with the catastrophe of the war and the destruction of yandavas just to name a few.

Comment: I do not understand. He killed a lot of bad demons, right? He restored dharma in that sense.

Comment: Yea he did kill deamon, but his main goal was to instill dharma in the political world if the times, so that rulers would follow righteousness, and yet his whole dynasty destroyed itself, his sons killed each other.

Comment: in your earlier question you had wrongly mentioned krishna as killer.. now this question is  intentionaly defame krishna earlier question i taught it was unintentionly..

Comment: What are you talking about, what do you mean not a killer, he killed more people that he could count, why would this defame him? Why is this question opinion based, are there any references as to whether he felt like his mission and destiny to destroy non rightcous has been a success?

Comment: It was time if war so how does calling somebody a killer defame him? And where did I call Krishna a killer. Ive mistaken his father for an uncle but it was not intentionall.

Comment: @ArcDDD How about you read Scriptures? In that it is said, those who died in his clan where the avatar of gods, and other mythical higher intelligent beings. Who takes avatar with Lord Krishna to take part in his Lila, `divine play`. When the time came, they have to go back to their respective lokas. They have to die.

Comment: @ArcDDD  Also, Yes he killed many people. But can you tell me killing rapists is bad? Raksha is not a Human species but a Characteristic. Anyone can become Raksha. Asura is a Different Mythical human species. He killed only bad people. What you do is your things, not God? Otherwise, no Karma can happen. People who are bad in nature have to die. New bad people will come and take their place. It's up to you what you want to become good or bad?